# SRAM GXP crank installation and rear hub preload

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, sram

I just had some new BB bearings installed and am going to put the crank in but have two spacers/dust shields I am uncertain of position. I had everything laid out how it was removed but it got mixed up :(
Bike is a Trek Superfly 6 with a Sram GX crank. I have a note that the BB is "PF89.5 SRAM GXP" (Also how does one find a kit online for this? I relied on the LBS to figure that out but I do like to learn where/how etc...)
[Posted photos of the parts here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d77Zb.jpg)

Have not really been able to confirm where the two black spacers go? One on the left is kind of a seal. Other is what looks like an aluminum spacer. The new seals over the bearings are shown held on by a zip tie as they came back from the bike shop. I just want to ensure I get the order correct. And wonder if the black seal on the left of the first photo is no longer needed with the new bb bearings? I suspect the black spacer(on the right) goes on the drive side between the "Spring washer" and the crank. And the left seal I don't know, but suspect non drive side.

Also, for the rear wheel I replaced a bearing as well. Its a sealed bearing and just want to confirm how tight I put the "cone" nut in before locking the lock nut up against it. Does it get set finger tight to snug so there is no play in it by moving it with your hand? Then lock it with the lock nut?

I'm more used to working on cars than bikes and am trying to be careful as they seem like they would be easier to break things.

Answer (score 1):

By amazing co-incidence there happens to be a video on YouTube showing SRAM GXP crank removal and installation on a Bike Trek Superfly 6.

.

Referring to that video, on the non-drive side it's (from inboard to outboard): red rubber seal, black plastic spacer, metal wavy washer. On the drive side there is only the red rubber seal.

Looks like your bike shop has omitted the black spacer on the drive side.

Comment: There is an extra piece then? I have the red seal, black seal, spacer then wavy ring atm. The black seal seems to only really fit over top of the red seal. And without it it seems like the spacer did not take up enough room on its own without the additional black seal. The black seal is rubber with the aluminum backing. And seems sized to only fit over the read seal? But video definitely helps with the order of what was intended.